# How to save CNN prediction as image with float32 data type?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to output the CNN prediction result as float32 format. When I am using the following code, the image outputs are scaled between 0-255 with 8 bit format. How can I keep the float32?

```
pred= model.predict(X_test)

-> dtype('float32')

for i, image in enumerate(pred, 1):
    tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img(f'output_test/{i}.tif', image,scale=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to save the predictions to images with float32 data type, we can use `tifffile`. The edited code is:

```
import numpy as np
from tifffile import imsave

pred= model.predict(X_test)

for i, image in enumerate(pred, 1):
    imsave(f'output_test/{i}.tif', image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import array_to_img
from PIL import Image

pred = model.predict(X_test)
for i, im in enumerate(pred, 1):
    img = array_to_img(im, scale=False)
    img.save('saved_image_{}.png'.format(i), format="PNG")
```

Comment: @ azal, pred contains more than one array, how we can add a for loop to your code

Comment: @Sam  Please see my edit. In the format=='PNG'' you can choose one according to your needs and the available ones. If the answer suits your needs, please accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @ azal, here is the error to your code: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'array_to_img'

Comment: @ azal, this is the new error: ValueError: Expected image array to have rank 3 (single image). Got array with shape: (2176, 16, 16, 1)

Comment: @Sam try it again, there was a typo in the code.

Comment: @Sam can you please accept the answer if it worked for you?

Comment: @ azal, the output images are in 8 bit data type, not float32